# SQL (postgres): summing a table some easier way?

Tags: sql, postgresql

This is kinda 101 here, but I have a temporary table getting populated like:

```
SELECT name, department, SUM(items) items INTO TEMPORARY TABLE foo 
FROM other_table 
GROUP BY name, department;
```

That's the gist, there are about 50 columns, so 50 `SUM()` calls. Then I have another rollup like so:

```
INSERT INTO foo SELECT name, 'sales', SUM(items) items 
FROM foo 
WHERE department in ('a', 'b') 
GROUP BY name;
```

This gets a little tedious script-writing-wise with the number of columns and the department rollup/splits (and the speed) and I was wondering if there was some way of doing this more efficiently. Though maybe this the only way.

Comment: What other 49 columns are you trying to `sum`?

Comment: I dont think the question is clear in show what you want. A small sample data and expect result will help. And your sample this recursion is ok ? INSERT INTO **foo** FROM **foo** ?

Answer (score 1):

With a decent editor that has a column-editing mode it is trivial to get a list of columns for a table, and edit them to get whatever functions applied to them that you want.

So:

```
\d my_table
```

Then copy the result into your editor, trim the fat away, surround the column names with "Sum(" and ")", and copy the column name as a column alias with a comma after it.

I use Sublime Text 2, but UltraEdit or almost any "professional" text editor will do this.

Answer (score 0):

For ease of use, try looking into a Materialized View...

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/rules-materializedviews.html

Other options include putting the query into a view, which the query would be ran every time you reference the view (which you could make "temporary" even, dropping it at the end of the session).

Answer (score 0):

Can you sum them all at once?

```
SELECT 
  name, 
  department, 
  SUM(items)   AS items, 
  SUM(alpha)   AS alpha,
  SUM(bravo)   AS bravo
  SUM(charlie) AS charlie,
  SUM(delta)   AS delta   -- etc as required
INTO TEMPORARY TABLE foo 
FROM other_table 
GROUP BY name, department;
```

Then use just the relevant column in your INSERTs:

```
INSERT INTO foo SELECT name, 'sales', SUM(items) items 
FROM foo 
WHERE department in ('a', 'b') 
GROUP BY name;

INSERT INTO foo SELECT name, 'alpha', SUM(alpha) items 
FROM foo 
WHERE department in ('a', 'b') 
GROUP BY name;
```

or even perhaps;

```
INSERT INTO foo SELECT name, 'alpha', SUM(alpha) items, 
                             'bravo', SUM(bravo) bravo -- etc 
FROM foo 
WHERE department in ('a', 'b') 
GROUP BY name;
```